# ag-grid - filter string as numeric value without changing the data type

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag-grid table with a column defined as follows:

```
{ headerName: 'Population', field: 'properties.population', sortable: true, filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter'}
```

The data i receive is for population is a string with a numeric value inside, for example:

```
[
{
"properties": {
        "state": "Alabama",
        "name": "Montgomery",
        "population": "199518"
      }
},
{
"properties": {
        "state": "Alaska",
        "name": "Juneau",
        "population": "32094"
      }
}
]
```

Which means the filter won't work.

I worked around this by changing the data in the component

```
this.data.forEach(item => {item.properties.population= Number(item.properties.population)});
```

Is there another solution in the field of ag-grid to change the filter behavior in filterParams or something else to avoid this data manipulation?

Comment: Is `properties` inside an array? Can you show the complete response?

Comment: Yes, inside an array. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Check the modified answer

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this via valueGetter in the column def

```
{ headerName: 'Population', 
field: 'properties.population', 
sortable: true, 
filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
valueGetter: (params) => { return parseInt(params.data.population) }
}
```

More information about valueGetter in ag-grid documentation:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters/#example-getters-and-formatters

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
data:any = [
    {
      properties: {
        state: "Alabama",
        name: "Montgomery",
        population: "199518"
      }
    },
    {
      properties: {
        state: "Alaska",
        name: "Juneau",
        population: "32094"
      }
    }
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.data.forEach(item => {
      item.properties.population = Number(item.properties.population)
    });
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1koz2a?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for an ag-grid solution without going through all the data and change the population values.

Comment: Show your ad-grid code, it will be good if you share it in stackbiltz